# Why MvvmLight Over Mvvm in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

While creating app in Xamarin Forms using Mvvm and MvvmLight, couldn't find significant reason of using MvvmLight. As all the features are already being provided by the xamarin forms/.net.

So if someone could point out the significance of MvvmLight (maybe with an example)?

Comment: MvvmLight is a framework as far as I am concerned, Xamarin.Forms doesn't have a out-of-the-box MVVM Framework, you have to implement it yourself. From the quick look at the documentation it also doesn't have message aggregators, navigation services or Delegate/Command implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably just what people are used to using with WPF. Instead of re-learning the terminology of Xamarin.Forms Mvvm they stick with Mvvmlight.

There are probably other reasons. Mvvmlight focus solely on Mvvm where as Xamarin.Forms resources are more spread out so may not adapt to design pattern changes as quickly as MvvmLight.

If I were choosing an Mvvm library to use I would choose MvvmLight for the reasons stated above

Answer (score 2):

I have been using MVVM light for some time, the one thing I love is that You can make UI changes to datatemplates during design time.

I am still new to Xamarin MVVM, but from what I can tell you have no design time preview in the shared project(Xamarin Forms) yet.
So MVVM light may not give you such an advantage.

Questions to ask yourself is why you would need an MVVM library in the first place.